# Where do the spawn() functions (declared in "spawn.h") come from?

Tags: c, spawn

I am unable to compile this simple program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<spawn.h>
#include<process.h>

int main(){
    printf("Spawning new process...\n");
    spawnl(P_WAIT,"curl","www.google.co.in",NULL);
    system("cls");
    printf("Program execution completed somehow!\n");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried using following command:

```
g++ filename.cpp -l -o filename.cpp
```

Result: `ld.exe cannot find -l exit with status 1`

```
g++ filename.cpp -o filename
```

Result: `error: spawn.h No such file or directory.`

Is there a problem with my MinGW installation? I am using Windows 7 32 bit and MinGW.

Comment: Why you don't use std::cout instead of printf()?

Comment: what is (where is it from) spawn/spwan.h? It certainly is not standard C++. Otoh, nothing in your program seems to hint that it is C++, so are you sure you want a C++ answer and not a C answer?

Comment: @pst : IDK. I have been googling for it. It wasn't on my system, I download this and some other related .h files but than some other errors kept coming. So I removed them too. I am windows user and finding it very difficult to manage this library stuff while compiling. Do I need to download some library?

Comment: @R.M. :R.M. : Was coding in C for past some months, then decieded to go to C++ for this particular program only, because I love the concept of classes. So now writing most of program in C, except for using some features of C++

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Changed the tag. I am myself trying to figure out which library contains this,whether it is or not on my system. I am used to code in Java and everything seems to be in one place there. Now this library thing for every function I use-pthread, spawn and similar functions making me look like a fool.

Comment: @vish213 Ok. In this case the C tag is more appropriated: I saw you changed it. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`spawn.h` is not a standard C/C++ header.  POSIX defines a non-standard `<spawn.h>` header, but it doesn't define a `spawnl` function, and Windows is not a POSIX-conforming system anyways.

Windows does define the [`_spawnl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wweek9sc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) function in `<process.h>`, so the easiest thing to do would be to just remove the inclusion of `<spawn.h>` and use that instead.  You could also rewrite your code to use the Windows function [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: The POSIX spawning functions all start with `posix_`, so the code can't be intending to use [POSIX `<spawn.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/spawn.h.html#tag_13_44).  And neither `<conio.h>` nor `<process.h>` is a POSIX header, either.

Comment: Means-Install Cygwin, and compile it there. Will my somehow compiled program run on Windows system NOT having Cygwin?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spawn_(computing)  Someone gave me this link. Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: @vish213: That link is essentially correct, except the functions have been renamed to have a leading underscore.  Nowhere does that article mention any header named `<spawn.h>`, except for a reference to article mentioning the different POSIX functions.